# Is it right that I solve a Riemann-Stieltjes integral.

Tags: integration, riemann-integration

Given $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ like the following: 
\begin{align}
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 \quad x\in[-1, 0)\\
1 \quad x\in[0, 1]
\end{cases}
&& \phi(x) = \begin{cases}
0 \quad x\in[-1, 0]\\
1 \quad x\in(0, 1]
\end{cases}
\end{align}

For any partition $\Gamma=\{x_i\}_{i=0}^m, 0=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_m=1$, the Riemann-Stieltjes sum is
\begin{align}
R_\Gamma[f, \phi]=\sum_{i=1}^m f(\xi_i)\left[\phi(x_i)-\phi(x_{i-1})\right]
\end{align}
where $\xi_i$ is any point in $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$.

Therefore, \begin{align}
R_\Gamma[f, \phi]&=\sum_{i=1}^m f(\xi_i)\left[\phi(x_i)-\phi(x_{i-1})\right]\\
&=f(\xi_1)\left[\phi(x_1)-\phi(x_0)\right] + \sum_{i=2}^m f(\xi_i)\left[\phi(x_i)-\phi(x_{i-1})\right]\\
&=1\cdot[1-0]+ 0 \quad \text{since } [\phi(x_i)-\phi(x_{i-1})] \text{ are all zero for } i=2, 3, \cdots, m\\
&=1
\end{align}

Therefore, $$
\int_0^1 fd\phi = \lim_{\max\{\Delta x_i\}\to0} R_\Gamma[f, \phi] = 1
$$

---

However, my professor told us it is zero. (without any explanation.)

Is it real zero? If so, where is fault in my process?

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the $f$ and $\phi$ you defined, $\int_0^1 f \; d\phi$ is indeed $1$.
The instructor made a mistake.

Comment: Thank you!!! Thanks to you, I got confidence.